# YSlow - effective for data intensive sites

Tags: yslow

I wanted to know that is YSlow effective for any particular kind of web sites , for e.g. would it really help in data intensive sites.

And is there any way to test how much improvement (may be what grade it could bring up to) it can give before actually implementing the changes it suggests?

Answer (score 1):

No, YSlow is not designed to improve data intensive, if you meant heavy Ajax; it's more for page load and consecutive loads of a given page, although there're 2 ajax rules.
If you run yslow on a page you can share the results via Twitter or Facebook, the generated link points to YSlow Scoremeter which allows you to play with each individual rule scores so you have an idea what changes to implement. e.g.:

YSlow grade C for http://www.cnn.com/ http://yslow.org/scoremeter/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cnn.com%2F&grade=C&ynumreq=0&ycdn=0&yexpires=0&ycompress=78&yjsbottom=75&yexpressions=88&ydns=50&yminify=90&yetags=45&ymindom=49&ycookiefree=55&ynofilter=55&yfavicon=90 via @yslow

Comment: Didn't know about that scoremeter, very useful.

Comment: @marcelduran - Thanks for that, i guess it makes sense. And even I didn't know about the score meter, looks interesting.